# Vanity address generator for contracts

Tags: smart-contracts, address

Is that even possible for Tezos contracts?

There is a vanity address "generator" in JS for tezos.

See [github](https://gist.github.com/baketzforme/e27d46d70e949ea9953b11902c2fa4fe)

So looking for something like this but for Tezos contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the address of a smart-contract is the hash of parameters including for example the timestamp of the block in which the contract is originated. unlike implicit addresses which are the hash of a public key. So it's not really possible to do vanity with smart-contract addresses.

All you can do is dry-run in a loop until you find an address that suits you and hope that the operation will commit to the same block at which you did the last dry-run.