# Is it possible to generate a vanity rollup address?

Tags: rollup, smart-rollup

Is it possible to create vanity rollup addresses?
I believe projects that will use a rollup would make use of that to represent their brand or name etc.

It is possible with Tezos addresses and there is this JS "[generator](https://gist.github.com/baketzforme/e27d46d70e949ea9953b11902c2fa4fe)".

With contracts it is not possible according to this [response](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/vanity-address-generator-for-contracts).

Is this the same case for rollups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the same answer as for smart contracts, unfortunately.

Comment: To be precise, that's not impossible but very unlikely to succeed because the nonce used to generate the address is hard difficult to control and for each try, someone needs to generate a valid so-called origination proof (that is costly if you need to do many iterations).

Comment: What else does the origination proof depend on besides the boot sector?